# python regex and writing file inquiry

Tags: python, regex

I got a question about how to write on one file after changed using regex and loop.

I want to change '`left`' of '`text-align:left;`' under '`p.FM_table_cell_body* {`'.
(`*` means number)

it's a css example file as follow:

```
file = '''p.FM_table_cell_body1 {
    margin-left:0.000pt;
    margin-right:0.000pt;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body2 {
    margin-left:0.000pt;
    margin-right:0.000pt;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body3 {
    margin-left:0.000pt;
    margin-right:0.000pt;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0.000pt;
}'''
```

and this is what i am trying

```
import re

for A in range(2,4) :  # these numbers are just example, they can be changed.
    print(A)
    with open ("C:\\TEST\\HTML\\Output_sample1\\Responsive HTML5\\Output_test.css","wt",encoding="utf-8") as file_new :
        new_content = re.sub(r"(p\.FM_table_cell_body" + str(A) + " {[^}]+text-align:)left", r"\1center", file)
        file_new.write(str(new_content))
```

but this code changes only '`text-align:center;`' under '`FM_table_cell_body3`'.

The output that I want is as below:

```
file_new = '''p.FM_table_cell_body1 {
    margin-left:0.000pt;
    margin-right:0.000pt;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body2 {
    margin-left:0.000pt;
    margin-right:0.000pt;
    text-align:center;   # 'left' is changed to 'center'
    text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body3 {
    margin-left:0.000pt;
    margin-right:0.000pt;
    text-align:center;  # 'left' is changed to 'center'
    text-indent:0.000pt;
}'''
```

which part do I modify?

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop you're just writing the current replacement, overwriting what was done on the previous iteration.

You should update the `new_content` string each time through the loop, then write to the file at the end.

```
import re

new_content = file
for A in range(2,4) :  # these numbers are just example, they can be changed.
    print(A)
    new_content = re.sub(r"(p\.FM_table_cell_body" + str(A) + " {[^}]+text-align:)left", r"\1center", new_content)
with open ("C:\\TEST\\HTML\\Output_sample1\\Responsive HTML5\\Output_test.css","wt",encoding="utf-8") as file_new :
    file_new.write(str(new_content))
```

Comment: Oh Barmar! Great! I was stucked actually but you save me thank you.